# how to calculate the limit without use of derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate $$\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x)^{\frac{1}{x^{2}}}$$ without the use of l'Hopitals rule(and other derivative based, if any), with just plain limits' rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left[(1+\cos x-1)^{\dfrac1{\cos x-1}}\right]^{\dfrac{\cos x-1}{x^2}}$$

The inner limit converges to $e$

For the exponent,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}=-\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{(\cos x+1)}\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2$$

Comment: @wirm, See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061142/evaluate-lim-x%E2%86%920-left-frac1-tan-x1-sin-x-right1-x2/1061152#1061152

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ so $\sin x {\to} x$ as ${x \to 0}$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x)^{\frac{1}{x^{2}}}=\lim_{x \to 0} (1-(\sin x)^2)^{\frac{1}{2x^{2}}}=\lim_{x \to 0} (1- x^2)^{\frac{1}{2x^{2}}}=(\lim_{-x^2 \to 0} (1+(- x^2))^{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}})^{-\frac12}=e^{-\frac12}$$